# Setting a variable based on the number of highlighted tabs in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the number of workbooks whose tab colors are the standard automatic color.

I have a way to do this but it requires looping through each worksheet in the workbook and increasing the count this way. Ie like so:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Long

    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    n = 0

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Tab.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    Debug.Print (n)
    End Sub
```

I know there is a worksheet function, one that can count the total number of worksheets in a workbook... ie:

```
n = wb.Worksheets.Count
```

Can one adjust this to include an if clause? 
ie `n=wb.worksheets.countif` ? And if so can this be adjusted to fit my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? I believe that's the best way to go about it.

Comment: Why not use a user defined function based on your code? `nRed = wsCountIfRed(wb)` or `nBlue = wsCountIfBlue(wb)`

Comment: @dwirony Always interested to learn about ways that could make the code less lines, especially if there was a countif function for worksheets I could use this idea going forward. If this is the best way to do this then I will continue to do it that way. Thanks

Comment: @SadMrFrown Got it - if your code is working and you're just looking to make it more efficient/simpler, I'd suggest bringing it over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dwirony Ah okay, apologies! I didn't realize that site existed. Thanks.

Comment: @SadMrFrown No worries!

Comment: There is no one-liner. Stick with what you have.